# How safe is it to use cloud proxy for connection between VM and Paas instance in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

As I came to know that cloud proxy uses the public IP in the background. So how safe is it to use cloud proxy and what is the background process and how safe it is if we are using public IP in google cloud.

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered. To get a specific answer to a specific question, you should make the question more substantive, describe in brief the solution architecture, share links to the Google product documentation you've obtained the information from, security vulnerabilities you see in the existing solution and potential ways to exploit them.

Comment: @mebius99 Okay to narrow it down, when you enable public IP for a Cloud SQL instance, that instance is exposed to the internet. However, you can configure allowed public IP ranges so only those IP ranges will have access to the instance. I want to know how secure is this kind of approach. what is the background process of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a PaaS-based client application, most likely it has an ephemeral IP address. In this situation, restricting access based on the range of source IP addresses may be ineffective.

In such a case using Cloud SQL Proxy is optimal. As with many services that use public IP address, Google Cloud Proxy protects traffic in public networks by encryption. Traffic between the proxy client and the proxy server process is passed through the secure tunnel encrypted using AES cipher.

Apart from that, The SQL Proxy requires authentication and uses IAM to restrict access to the SQL instance.

You can find more information in the documentation:

[Cloud SQL > Doc > MySQL > Connecting to Cloud SQL from external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app)

[Cloud SQL > Doc > MySQL > About the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy):

> The Cloud SQL Proxy provides **secure access** to your instances
> without the need for authorized networks or for configuring SSL. The
> proxy automatically **encrypts traffic** to and from the database
> using TLS 1.2 with a 128-bit AES cipher; SSL certificates are used to
> verify client and server identities.
> The proxy uses a **secure
> tunnel** to communicate with its companion process running on the SQL
> server.
> The proxy **requires authentication**. When you use a service
> account to provide the credentials for the proxy, you must create it
> with sufficient permissions: a role that includes the
> `cloudsql.instances.connect` permission.

[Cloud SQL > Doc > MySQL > Connecting from App Engine standard environment to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard):

> App Engine provides a mechanism that connects using the Cloud SQL
> Proxy.
> Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to
> your Cloud SQL instance's unix domain socket using the format:
> `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`.
> These connections are
> automatically **encrypted** without any additional configuration.

Also, you may configure your systems so that use Private IP as described here:

[Cloud SQL > Doc > MySQL > Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip)